# Issue passing a array to a variable argument character parameter

Tags: java

I'm creating anonymous array and passing it to a method which is declared to receive a variable argument character...

I'm wondering how the below code will run successfully, I'm passing a array of characters {'A','B','C,'D'} and the method can receive only characters...shouldn't it fail with wrong types passed? ie; character array vs characters?

```
public class test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        callme(new char[]{'A','B','C','D'});
    }

    static void callme(char... c){
        for (char ch:c){
            System.out.println(ch);
        }

        }

}
```

Comment: `char...` is some sweet sugar.

Answer (score 3):

They are the same. A `char...` is a `char[]`

You can also write

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    callme('A','B','C','D');
}

static void callme(char... c){
    for (char ch : c) {
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine.  All the varargs syntax with `char...` actually does is that it is actually implemented as `callme(char[] c)`, and all the *callers* of that method who just pass in comma-separated `char`s will be converted to passing in an anonymous array, exactly as you did by hand.